# check if the value falls within range powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code to check if the value falls under provided range

```
            $RX_Val = "-2.7"
            $TX_Val = "-3.4"
            
            $RX_Bool = $RX_Val -in -1..-4
            $TX_Bool = $TX_Val -in -1..-4

            if(([string]$RX_Bool -eq 'False') -or ([string]$TX_Bool -eq 'False'))
            {
                $RXTX_Data | Out-File -FilePath "E:\Port_$file_name" -Force
            }
```

Both the values falls within the range but still `$RX_Bool` and `$TX_Bool` returning `False` in place of `True`

Please let me know what I have done wrong here

Comment: Why are you using strings for what appears to be float/decimal values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple errors:
First, you assigned STRINGS to `$RX_Val` and `$TX_Val`, not numbers.

Second, `-1..-4` will create a array of INTEGERS.

Either of those will result in a `$False`

Also, you are comparing a stringification of a boolean? Why?

Go with classics:

```
$RX_Val = -2.7
$TX_Val = -3.4

$MinValue = -4
$MaxValue = -1

$RX_Bool = ($RX_Val -le $MaxValue) -and ($RX_Val -ge $MinValue)
$TX_Bool = ($TX_Val -le $MaxValue) -and ($TX_Val -ge $MinValue)

# if at least one of them is not true
if (-not ($RX_Bool -and $TX_Bool)) { 
    'MAGIC !'
}
# if BOTH are true
else {
    'different magic'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but still with the given values `$RX_Bool = ($RX_Val -le $MaxValue) -and ($RX_Val -ge $MinValue)` this is returning `False`. `-2.7` should return `true` as it is within value

Comment: on my system, using both powershell 7.4 and 5.1, the result I get is `True`. Are you sure you are copying i right?

Comment: Yes. I am executing the same code you gave. but no luck

Comment: Then I am baffled. Even [this website](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fAQhUgiLiwxJzFGwVdI30zLnAQiFwIWM9Ey6ImG9mHlCsNBUkagIVSqyACxlClQFNc8rPB@nVgJmsm5OKUKupoJuYl4IkmZ6KMFsTbj3cjBB8ZoRgNYML5oj//wE) returns `True` as expected.

Comment: What is the type you considered for `$RX_Val` and `$TX_Val`

Comment: the same I posted. I also tested with various different values, but the script always returned the expected results.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the previous question. `$RX_Val` and `$TX_Val` are `[Double]`.

Comment: worked now. had to explicitly mention the datatype to `[Double]`. thanks